# SpringBoot Caching isn't caching data, although it seems to auto-wire the @Cacheable method successfully

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I have a SpringBoot application to which I have been adding caching functionality. I started with REDIS as my caching provider, but the underlying caching failed to work as expected. I have therefore simplified to the default SpringBoot-provided caching, still without success.  Something is blocking caching from functioning.

NOTE: I did successfully enable caching in a *separate* test application (also SpringBoot) that I built in just a few hours without any issues.  So whatever is blocking caching in my actual service application is not intuitive to me.

My initial method that I am trying to cache passes in a String representation of a URI to get back a secret from AWS.  The response is a String also.  This should be trivial for caching.

*I have scoured a number of similar posts on StackOverflow, and ran through tutorials on caching using Spring's functionality, but I've clearly missed something...*

**What I've tried**:

- The URI being passed in is not dynamic, and does not change.  I have confirmed that the response is also the same.  Yet Spring is not caching it.
- I have confirmed that the import statements I am using are Spring's, and should be correct.
- The method I have marked as `@Cacheable` is located in a separate class
- I have marked my application with the `@EnableCaching` annotation.
- Created a separate Configuration class for caching, to override time to live and other functionality, but even disabling that class entirely, and moving the `@EnableCaching` annotation to my main method where my SprinBootApplication executes, does not work.

For example, here is my application's starting point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableAsync
public class MdhApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MdhApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

I also enabled TRACE-level logging for Spring's cache package [`org.springframework.cache`], which allows me to see the following:

```
Adding cacheable method 'getSecret' with attribute:
   [Builder[String org.mdh.service.AwsSecretsManager.getSecret(String)] 
    caches=[graphSecret] | key='' | keyGenerator='' 
       | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false']
```

So I know that Spring is at least auto-wiring up the correct method during startup.  Debugging my application, it is clear that Spring added the annotated method as cacheable, and showed the expected cache as having been created.

Then, when testing my **test app** (where SpringBoot's caching ***does*** work), I additionally saw every trip through the service logged to my console.

- As expected, the first call with a given ID couldn't be found, and it created a cache entry.
- That key was found in the cache for every subsequent call using that ID, and Spring used it.

Here is the additional SpringBoot Caching that I see logged in my test app, but not the actual service application I am adding caching to:

```
TRACE 28148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor   : Computed cache key '4' for operation Builder
TRACE 28148 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor   : No cache entry for key '4' in cache(s) [student]
TRACE 28148 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor   : Cache entry for key '4' found in cache 'student'
```

**PROBLEM**:  Yet with my actual service, I do not see ***any*** of the additional outputs that I saw in my test app.

- There are no lines logged that the cache is checked each time my method is called.
- There isn't any indication that it has found the cache, nor that it is even trying to find the cache entry.
- The only details about the cache is during application startup, when the Configuration class is auto-wired, and the `@Cacheable` method is loaded.

**QUESTION**:  What will prevent Spring from using the cache that I have established for a method that has been marked **`@Cacheable`**?

The most obvious cause that I can think of would be calling a method marked as `@Cacheable` from another method within the same bean/class, thus preventing Spring's AOP functionality from being able to proxy the method.  But I have placed this method in a separate service class, so I don't *think* that should be a problem.

**QUESTION**:  Are there any other scenarios in which I may have inadvertently defeated Spring's AOP / Proxy mechanism?

*Either the issue is obscure, or it is something fundamental that I have missed.  If you have an idea of what could be causing this, please share.  :-)*

Comment: This is really hard to say. Is current cache in a normal `@Service` class? Did you try to create a new empty test service and test it in your normal application... than you see if its a general problem or maybe only from this specific position.

Comment: Just a workaround if the url and the response dosen't change can't you use `@PostConstruct` to get the secret?

Comment: pL4Gu33: Yes, it is a normal @Service class, auto-wired as such (org.springframework.stereotype.Service).  If by "current cache" you are indicating the one that is working, the service that IS caching correctly is my test service, empty except for a handful of classes to test caching.

But that is a good thought.  I can try wiring up another method somewhere else in my normal/real service, and see if it exhibits the same failure to cache issue.

Comment: Pp88:  Thanks for the idea.  I was really stumped on this issue, so every idea is worth consideration.  I haven't used the @ PostConstruct annotation for a long time, but it seemed like it was a bad idea to use in Spring projects, where classes are auto-wired in during startup using Spring's IoC (Inversion of Control).  The reason to use @ PostConstruct is to defer certain events until after objects have been instantiated.  So it makes sense that it might be a valid work-around for me.  I tried it, but didn't reach any success, unfortunately.

Comment: FYI - an opinionated article in which the author describes why @PostConstruct isn't ideal for some applications: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/stop-using-postconstruct-in-your-java-applications-2a66fb202cb8

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging and analysis, I identified and fixed the caching issue that was preventing my service method from being cached.

I had tried everything I could possibly think of, and I had also scoured multiple tutorial sites as well as here on Stack Overflow.  Caching through the Spring Framework *should not* be this challenging.  I knew I was missing something fundamental.

One very helpful suggestion I received was to alter the logging level.  Although increasing the logging verbosity didn't explicitly identify the *actual* problem, it illuminated additional information.  By enabling TRACE mode on Spring's caching package, I immediately saw that my caching layer *was* configured and working by the logs that were output.

**CAUSE:  I hadn't yet added the service class I had annotated as `@Cacheable` to my constructor injector.  It's a pattern that I generally follow, but I missed it here.**

When I had written my initial AWS Utility class to retrieve secrets (among other things), I directly instantiated the service class within the controller methods that called my AWS new service.  Although I marked my utility class as a service (`@Service`), I never moved it into Spring's service constructor within each controller method.

*EXAMPLE: This is where I should have instantiated my service for Spring to inject it properly so that Spring's caching could be properly applied:*

```
public DataFetcher(D365AccessService d365AccessService, AssignmentService assignmentService, AwsSecretsManager awsSecretsManager) {
   this.d365Service = d365Service;
   this.assignmentService = assignmentService;
   this.awsSecretsManager = awsSecretsManager;
}
```

Thus, caching was not occurring through Spring because the service I was trying to cache wasn't connected up properly like my other services.  Through the IoC container (Inversion of Control) that Spring uses when auto-wiring classes, Spring's caching layer was proxying a *different* object instance (probably the autowired one I should have been using) and so the explicitly instantiated object never picked up.

**RESOLUTION**:  Once I added it properly to be an additional service in the constructor, and let Spring wire things up correctly, caching immediately began working as expected.  Just an oversight on my part, but annoying to chase down.  Learned my lesson.  : - )

NOTE:  The beauty of frameworks like Spring, is that even though they are often opinionated frameworks, they encourage us to do things right...  resulting in a far more efficient, robust, and elegant solution at the end of the day.